# propType for accepting a component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs

Given this contrived example, what is the best definition of `componentType`?

```
const componentType = PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.shape({render: PropTypes.func.isRequired}), // React.createClass / React.Component ...better way to describe?
    PropTypes.func,                                       // Stateless function
    // others?
]);

const Selector = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        components: PropTypes.arrayOf(componentType).isRequired,
        index:      PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    },

    render() {
        const Component = this.props.components[this.props.index];
        return (
            <Component />
        );
    }
});
```

`PropTypes.node` is not I'm looking for; its usage would look like this:

```
<Selector components={[<ThingA  />, <ThingB  />]} />
```

whereas I want something that would look like:

```
<Selector components={[ThingA, ThingB]} />
```

I want to pass types, not instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I crossposted to github and got [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5143#issuecomment-147473269). So it should be:

```
const componentType = PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.func])
```

`func` covers types from "classic" react components, ES6 classes, and stateless function components. `string` covers the native element case (eg "div").

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be most up to date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784547/4993912

TLDR;

```
const propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.elementType,
    requiredComponent: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

youre looking for a combination of `arrayOf` and `element`. the list of propTypes can be found on the [Reusable Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) page of the docs.

I'd expect it would look something like this:

```
components: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.element)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how react-router handles it [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js):

```
import React from "react";
import { isValidElementType } from "react-is";

Route.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.node]),
    component: (props, propName) => {
      if (props[propName] && !isValidElementType(props[propName])) {
        return new Error(
          `Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component`
        );
      }
    },
    exact: PropTypes.bool,
    location: PropTypes.object,
    path: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.string,
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
    ]),
    render: PropTypes.func,
    sensitive: PropTypes.bool,
    strict: PropTypes.bool
  };
```