# React propTypes component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

How can I validate that the supplied prop is a component class (not instance)?

e.g.

```
export default class TimelineWithPicker extends React.PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        component: PropTypes.any, // <-- how can I validate that this is a component class (or stateless functional component)?
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <this.props.component {...this.props} start={this.state.start}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

For anyone using `PropTypes >= 15.7.0` a new `PropTypes.elementType` was added in this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211) and was released on [february 10, 2019](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/commit/3807e16445eea9959b876a62306e1d1f94697685).

This prop type supports all components (native components, stateless components, stateful components, forward refs `React.forwardRef`, context providers/consumers).

And it throws a warning when is not any of those elements, it also throws a warning when the prop passed is an element (`PropTypes.element`) and not a type.

Finally you can use it like any other prop type:

```js
const propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.elementType,
    requiredComponent: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: If I understand what a [React element](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) is, this prop type is actually quite badly named :

> One might confuse elements with a more widely known concept of “components”.

Answer (score 26):

EDITED: Added React's [FancyButton](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) example to codesandbox as well as a custom prop checking function that works with the new `React.forwardRef` api in React 16.3. The `React.forwardRef` api returns an object with a `render` function. I'm using the following custom prop checker to verify this prop type. - Thanks for Ivan Samovar for noticing this need.

```
FancyButton: function (props, propName, componentName) {
  if(!props[propName] || typeof(props[propName].render) != 'function') {
    return new Error(`${propName}.render must be a function!`);
  }
}
```

You'll want to use <del>`PropTypes.element`</del>. Actually... `PropType.func` works for both stateless functional components and class components.

I've made a sandbox to prove that this works... Figured this was needed considering I gave you erroneous information at first. Very sorry about that!

Working [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/znj0nyxll)!

Here is the code for the test in case link goes dead:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>I'm a class component</p>
  }
}

const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;

const FSComponent = () => (
    <p>I'm a functional stateless component</p>
);

const Test = ({ ClassComponent, FSComponent, FancyButton }) => (
  <div>
    <ClassComponent />
    <FSComponent />
    <FancyButton />
  </div>
);
Test.propTypes = {
  ClassComponent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  FSComponent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  FancyButton: function (props, propName, componentName) {
    if(!props[propName] || typeof(props[propName].render) != 'function') {
      return new Error(`${propName}.render must be a function!`);
    }
  },
}

render(<Test
         ClassComponent={ ClassComponent }
         FSComponent={ FSComponent }
         FancyButton={ FancyButton } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Also use `oneOfType` for different types: `PropTypes.oneOfType([...])`

Comment: Isn't that an instance? I thought `<Foo>` (aka `React.createElement(Foo, null)`) was a react element, whereas I want to check for raw `Foo`.

Comment: Nope :) There's a separate PropType for that.

Comment: @btzr please check update if you have not resolved this issue. I made a sandbox so that you can see THIS does work. I ran into this in something I'm working on today, used element and thought, "dang... i need to correct that". Documentation could use updating about this.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with components wrapped to `React.forwardRef` – new API introduced in react 16.3

Comment: @IvanSamovar Not true, it works perfectly. Here is the updated [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/znj0nyxll) with a copy paste of React's FancyButton example into it.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I see error in your sandbox console 
`Failed prop type: Invalid prop \`FancyButton\` of type \`object\` supplied to \`Test\`, expected \`function\`.`

screenshot http://take.ms/JwL0v

Comment: @IvanSamovar You're right. Not sure how I missed that, I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: so regarding to initial question there is no simple prop type that can validate any possible component type

Comment: That was not the initial question. It was how to validate a class component. Though as of React v16 there seems to not be one catch all PropType. You could always use `PropTypes.oneOfType(PropTypes.func, customPropTypeFunc).isRequired;`