# Use imported modules in React propType definitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I need `Row`s children to all be instances of the `Col` component:
The following code worked when Row and Col were in the same file, but when I import Col into Row I get this error:
`Warning: Failed prop type: Cannot call a class as a function`

**How can variables and imports be used in propType definitions?**
(building with webpack)

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Col from './Col';

export default class Row extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.shape({ type: Col }),
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ type: Col }))
    ]).isRequired,
......
```

Comment: Show your `Col`. Do you have `class Col extends React.Component` or just `class Col {...`?

Comment: export default class Col extends React.Component {.....

Comment: >PropTypes.instanceOf() expects a regular JavaScript "class" and not a React class
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2979

Answer (score 0):

As the React devs themselves admit [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5143) , there is no one way to define a prop type for a component.

Perhaps the most generic possible option would be:

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.string, React.PropTypes.func])
```

If you're not concerned with strings (for native elements like "div") you can just do:

```
React.PropTypes.func
```

And if you want to get very specific, see this answer:

[React propTypes component class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315918/react-proptypes-component-class)